# Is there an idiom for "it was just an example"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Are there any idioms or succinct ways of expressing your resignation when you

- give an **example**
- the other person reacts with: *"that's not what I meant"*.

…but your intention was for the example to be interpreted *metaphorically*? "It was just an example."

Comment: ***Never mind...*** is the most common idiom, although particularly for "resignation" there are also e.g. ***I give up!*** and ***What's the use?***; both are usually preceded with a sigh spelt *Oh* or some sound indicating disgust / frustration, such as *Ugh* or *Argh!*

Comment: Broadly? No.

If you think there could be, why not show some research or exmples or preferbly, both?

Comment: I think this is more of  etiquette and a how to communicate more than an English language question. @WillCrawford 's suggestion "never mind" is an excellent way of expressing a mild rebuke of the other's lack of good will in engagement IF the "that's not what I meant" was not followed by an explanation of what they meant.  If you want to keep the conversation open(say with your child),  a "**I tried, what am I missing?**" would invite them to examine your words more broadly to form an explanation

Comment: "So says Captain Obtuse."

Comment: There is a vast difference between 'it was just an example' and 'it was a metaphor'. It is not clear which of the two the question is about.

Comment: There's also a vast difference between "expressing your resignation" and fully describing the situation/characterising fallacious reasoning.

Comment: I think the question is not clear.  Without what the other person said in the first place, before the allegedly irrelevant giving of the example, I do not see what the objection to the example giving might have been, let alone whether it was justified.

Comment: The idiom is "exempli gratia" ... "e.g.".

Answer (score 1):

— “It was meant metaphorically, of course”

— “Take it with ‘a grain of salt’, then, if you will” (piece of information may not be completely true or accurate)

— I was obviously “off target” please clarify what you did mean?

— I was speaking “in broad strokes” (you describe or show only the main or general points or features of it and not the fine or exact details)

— forgive my “turn of phrase” (a particular way of saying something or describing something)

Answer (score 0):

> give an example the other person reacts with: "that's not what I
> meant". …but your intention was for the example to be interpreted
> metaphorically? "It was just an example."

"Duh - It was just a metaphor"

> **Duh**
>
> used to show that you think a person or statement is stupid, or that
> something is **obvious** 
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/duh

"**Duh** - It was just a metaphor" means "Huh - **Obviously** it was just a metaphor!"

---

**Note that the intonation of the word duh is very important**

> Here's a pronunciation guide (duh does not only have to be used with questions. It can also refer to stupid statements)
> [The Word DUH - 1 Minute English Lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMBWoFE_xxs)

[billie eilish - saying “duh” for 3 mins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0i0IlSKn0sE)

[Search for duh](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=duh&atb=v245-1&iax=images&ia=images)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an insult, this one would be appropriate: **I can explain it to you, but I can't understand it for you.** [If Goodreads is to be believed](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/900678-i-can-explain-it-to-you-but-i-can-t-comprehend), this is derived from a statement by Edward Koch.

Answer (score -2):

It is one of the scenarios where the expression **casting pearls before swine** applies.

from [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cast-pearls-before-swine):

> *cast pearls before swine* ​ to offer something valuable or good to someone who does not know its value:
>
> *I'm afraid you're casting pearls before swine with your good advice –
>    he won't listen.*

And from [Collins Cobuild Idioms Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cast+pearls+before+swine):

> If you cast pearls before swine, you offer something valuable to
>   someone who is not good enough or clever enough to appreciate it.

The expression is from Matthew 7:6:

New International Version {[BibleHub](http://biblehub.com/matthew/7-6.htm)}

> "Do not give dogs what is sacred; do not throw your pearls to pigs. If
>   you do, they may trample them under their feet, and turn and tear you
>   to pieces.

[Note that this is a chiastic structure, A B B' A'; it is the dogs that might tear you to pieces, and the pigs that might trample the goodies into the mud.)

The metaphor has been further broadened to include anything worthwhile, not just at the overtly spiritual level. The possible unwarranted opposition from those one is trying to help is clear in the complete verse (and implicit in the usual shortened form).

So "I must remember to be careful not to cast pearls before swine," preferably not in the other person's hearing.